# Failed to load entry from component (IE) - Sharepoint SPFX

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I get this error running on IE, works fine on Chrome et al.

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5" (CompactCustomListWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5" (CompactCustomListWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5_0.0.1
 https://component-id.invalid/3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5_0.0.1 did not call System.register or AMD define. If loading a global module configure the global name via the meta exports property for script injection support.

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5" (CompactCustomListWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5_0.0.1
 https://component-id.invalid/3aac0bde-0ef1-46a1-a7f4-216112d395d5_0.0.1 did not call System.register or AMD define. If loading a global module configure the global name via the meta exports property for script injection support.
***CALLSTACK:
Error
   at t._generateErrorStackForIE (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:4:53963)
   at t (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:4:53499)
   at t (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:20:118832)
   at e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:20:128525)
   at e.buildLoadComponentError (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:20:124550)
   at Anonymous function (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:20:115044)
   at Anonymous function (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:1:16156)
   at F (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:1:16132)
   at C (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:1:15977)
   at B (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6c1243ef07241a9f41fe54d8c7adbc98.js:1:15565)
```

I have incorporated gulp clean into the build script so it always cleans before builds.

Someone suggested that the external CDN reference to Fabric was causing this issue? How would I bundle it myself?

Perhaps it is the sp web pnp js import that uses newer stuff - do I need to add poly fill to every tsx file that uses sp, or only the mainwebpart.ts? 
`import '@pnp/polyfill-ie11';`
(https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/polyfill/)

Comment: did you import any other packages than the standard ones from the spfx generator?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use `import '@pnp/polyfill-ie11';` in your [webpartname].ts file! So at the entry point of your application! From there it gets imported into the whole application and the polyfills are available!

Greetings, Joe